# angular 2 http post method Unexpected end of JSON input

Tags: angular2-services

```
public deptpostdbServer() {
    let headers = new Headers();
    headers.append('application/x-www-form-urlencoded', 'Content-Type');
    headers.append('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'POST');
    headers.append('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');

    return this.http
    .post('http://172.16.0.125:8090/buyR/api/saveDeptInfo/150/Software', headers)
    .map(res => res.json());

    public datapostDisplay() {
        this.deptpost = [];     
        this.sitehttpservice.deptpostdbServer().subscribe((res) => {
        this.deptpost.push(res);
    });

   ERROR SyntaxError: Unexpected end of JSON input
   at JSON.parse (<anonymous>)
   at Response.Body.json (body.ts:36)
   at MapSubscriber.eval [as project] (table.service.ts:77)
   at MapSubscriber._next (map.ts:75)
   at MapSubscriber.Subscriber.next (Subscriber.ts:95)
   at XMLHttpRequest.onLoad (xhr_backend.ts:104)
   at ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (zone.js:424)
   at Object.onInvokeTask (ng_zone.ts:253)
   at ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (zone.js:423)
   at Zone.runTask (zone.js:191)
   defaultErrorLogger @ errors.ts:42
  ErrorHandler.handleError @ error_handler.ts:69

   Post service 
     <div class="form-group" >
        First: <input type="text" [(ngModel)]="data.DeptCd" 
        placeholder="text"/>
        Last: <input type="text" [(ngModel)]="data.Desc" 
         placeholder="name"/>
        <button (click)="datapostDisplay()">Save</button>

    </div>
```

angular2 post service is json parse error . I have passed correct params. I can get from the database using API. from method I can call the API using post from textbox I cannot send post method I am getting json parse error.

Answer (score 0):

In your post request I see your headers but don't see any "params". You are essentially sending an empty post request. Just add your 2 field values in your request and that should resolve your error unless there is some other error in your remote server script. Your post request should look something like this:

```
    let headers = new Headers({ 'Content-Type': 'application/json' });
    let data = { postFieldName : postValue, postFieldName2 : postValue2 };
    let params = JSON.stringify(data);

    return this.http.post(URL, params, headers)
              .map(this.extractData)
              .catch(this.handleError);
```

Then you create an extractData method that will handle your http response. If the error persists than maybe check to see that your data is not undefined before sending out the post request.

[Check out documentation located here ›](https://angular.io/guide/http#send-data-to-the-server)